# Unable to set height of a div inside ion-content in ionic based application

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am a newbie to ionic. I am trying to centre 2 divs regardless of the amount of content, inside an `ion-content` tag on a page. Setting height to some percentage value is not working. Attaching a custom `centre` class is also not affecting the position of the divs. They are still stacked on top of each other taking only the space required.

Below is HTML:

```
<ion-content class="padding tab-dash-content centre">
  <div class="section1 padding centre">
    <h3>Section 1</h2>
    <h5>
      Sub Heading
    </h5>
    <p>
      Some multi Line text
    </p>
  </div>      
  <div class="section2 padding centre">
    <h3>Section 2</h3>        
    <h5>
      Sub Heading
    </h5>
    <p>
      Some multi line text
    </p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The CSS:

```
.centre { 
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
}

.section1,
.section2 {
    border: 2px solid #ffa733;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `height` from % to vh (vh
1/100th of the height of the viewport.)

```
.centre { 
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
}

.section1,
.section2 {
    border: 2px solid #ffa733;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: It is doing part of the job. The divs are resizing. But when I am resizing the browser window, the text is overflowing from the divs. Does the height and width of Viewport changes when we resize the window?

Comment: Try adding `overflow: auto;` to section class